# How to work around A/yoga: availableHeight is indefinite so heightMeasureMode must be YGMeasureModeUndefined

Tags: android, react-native

When I run the react native app I get the following error:

````
A/yoga: availableHeight is indefinite so heightMeasureMode must be YGMeasureModeUndefined
--------- beginning of crash
12-19 11:46:11.875 29289-29476/com.comp.projectname A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 29476 (mqt_native_modu)```
````

I'm using react-native 0.55.4 and read that upgrading fixes the issue but when I upgrade to the new react native it throw other errors

```
     E/unknown:JSDebuggerWebSocketClient: Error occurred, shutting down websocket connection: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { at com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSDebuggerWebSocketClient.onMessage(JSDebuggerWebSocketClient.java:198)
     E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call   com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaJSExecutor$ProxyExecutorException: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { at com.facebook.react.devsupport.WebsocketJavaScriptExecutor.loadApplicationScript(
         Caused by: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
     E/unknown:ReactNative: Unable to launch redbox because react activity is not available, here is the error that redbox would've displayed: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I also read that a couple of people had the issue even after updating so I decided to stay with 0.55.4 for this project if there is a work around.

is there a work around for A/yoga: availableHeight is indefinite so heightMeasureMode must be YGMeasureModeUndefined 
thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I was using react-native-navigation and went from single-screen-app to tab-base app. during the switch the error would occur as the tabs were loading. so I removed the single screen app called the tab base app then reset root to the login screen with the tabs hidden. This is a work around that worked for me.